# How to set up proxy in graphql?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I have problem with graphql server connection, I think it's proxy problem, but im not sure.
I try to do a search for this,but i can't find my problem.

Here is the error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 104.31.87.73:443",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 2
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "launches"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "launches": null
  }
}
```

Server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require("./schema");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`));
```

I try to set up proxy,but it's not working.

Can somebody help me how to set up a proxy in graphql?

Comment: Whatever error you're seeing is coming from the code inside your resolver for the `launches` field.

Comment: const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    launches: {
      type: new GraphQLList(LaunchType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches")

          .then(res => res.data);
      }
    }
  }
});

i can't find any problem.